# Save to a parallel directory in python

Tags: python, save, relative-path, working-directory

My file structure looks something like this:

```
ROOT
├── Admin
│   └── python_script.py
└── JSON
    └── target_file.out
```

OK, my Python file is in the admin folder.  I'm trying to save a file in the JSON folder.  I've done fine saving the file in the Admin folder, but now I need it to go where it is supposed to go, the JSON folder.  The target has to be relative so I can't do a absolute target.

Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer to help you, but this seems very basic to say the least: hence the downvote...

Comment: @Jro It is really simple because I don't know python.  I'm a .net programmer and today I had to deal with a small python script.  I've had no prior experience with it.  Luckily, somethings were common sense, this though has stumped me until now.

Comment: @jro: don't downvote the question. If the question is so simple (though it should not be the reason to downvote) then why your answer is incorrect?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: to quote the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask page: _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?_. The very first Google result for _python save file in relative folder_ returns a (StackOverflow) answer that on that page contains all the information needed. Therefore, my downvote. If I misinterpreted that _How to ask_ page, I would like to know what I misread.

Comment: If it is a duplicate then click the close button or just provide a link to the question in a comment. stackoverflow is a *destination* where google sents people. If there would be no answers to simple questions here where should google send people? Additionally, 1. don't close as duplicate if the wording is sufficiently different. google is not sentient it can't understand semantics and people tend to use different words for the same ideas. 2. google is not sentient so some prior knowledge in topic under research is required to use it efficiently. SO can be a place to provide that knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough, and a clear explanation. Thanks for taking the time to respond so thoroughly: it is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna store the file via a file-object you would do something like this:

```
# .  = -Root----Admin
# .. = -Root
# ../JSON = -Root----JSON
my_file = open("../JSON/targetfile", "w")
my_file.write("foo")
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Agreed that this is a more complete answer, so it gets my vote. Only thing I want to add is to use the `os.path.join` function for constructing the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If you always run the code from `Admin`, and the `JSON` folder is always at that relative point:

```
os.path.join('JSON', filename)
```

If you were in the `PythonScript` folder:

```
os.path.join('..', 'JSON', filename)
```